# What would be the qualifications for something to become a Minhag today?

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory

Assuming there exist some criteria for establishing minhag and minhag hamakom, and assuming minhagim could still come into being in today's times, what would be the qualifications for something to become a Minhag today?

Comment: Do you think today would be different than any other time? What could be involved besides people doing it?

Comment: @DoubleAA-that's what I was thinking - a bunch of people in a locale that do something their particular way long enough for it to be considered "customary" there.